# ImportError: No module named 'support'

Tags: python, module

I have already referred to all the question related to the **No module named `<module name>`** questions on StackOverflow and had no luck in addressing my specific issue. Hence, am posting this question.

I am currently working on a python project and am trying to run the `run_bsg.py` file from [this project](https://github.com/ixlan/BSG). However, I keep getting the following error.

#### Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nayantara/PycharmProjects/BSG/run_bsg.py", line 3, in <module>
    from interfaces.interface_configurator import InterfaceConfigurator
  File "/home/nayantara/PycharmProjects/BSG/interfaces/interface_configurator.py", line 1, in <module>
    from libraries.data_iterators.open_text_data_iterator import OpenTextDataIterator
  File "/home/nayantara/PycharmProjects/BSG/libraries/data_iterators/open_text_data_iterator.py", line 2, in <module>
    from support import deal_with_accents
ImportError: No module named 'support'
```

#### Python code

```
# this file contains an example on how to run the bayesian skip-gram model
import os
from interfaces.interface_configurator import InterfaceConfigurator
from libraries.evaluation.support import evaluate
from libraries.evaluation.lexsub.run_lexsub import run_lexsub

train_data_path = 'data/datafile.txt' 
vocab_file_path = 'vocabulary/2M.txt' 
output_folder_path = "output/2M/"  

# obtain the interface to interact with the model.
i_model = InterfaceConfigurator.get_interface(train_data_path, vocab_file_path, output_folder_path)

i_model.train_workflow()

# store the temporary vocab, because it can be different from the original one(e.g. smaller number of words)
vocab = i_model.vocab
temp_vocab_file_path = os.path.join(i_model.output_path, "vocab.txt")
vocab.write(temp_vocab_file_path)

mu_vecs = [os.path.join(i_model.output_path, "mu.vectors")]
sigma_vecs = [os.path.join(i_model.output_path, "sigma.vectors")]

# a complex of word embedding evaluations(word similarity, entailment, directional entailment)
evaluate(mu_vectors_files=mu_vecs, sigma_vectors_files=sigma_vecs, vocab_file=temp_vocab_file_path, log_sigmas=False,
         full_sim=True, vocab=vocab)

# run additionally lexical substitution evaluation
run_lexsub(input_folder=i_model.output_path, output_path=i_model.output_path)
```

**open_text_data_iterator.py**

```
from nltk import word_tokenize as default_tokenizer
from support import deal_with_accents
from libraries.utils.paths_and_files import get_file_paths

...
```

Any suggestion in this regard will be much appreciated

Comment: support is not an external library. It's a file within the `libraries/data-iterators/` directory

Comment: The error originates from `BSG/libraries/data_iterators/open_text_data_iterator.py` not able to find `BSG/libraries/data_iterators/support.py`. Are you launching from the program from the commandline?

Comment: Right. In that case, you'll need to edit line number two in the `open_text_data_iterator.py` file to `from libraries.data_iterators.support import deal_with_accents`

Comment: @razdi No. I simply tried running from my pycharm interface

Comment: @ClockSlave Thanks. It worked like magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm reposting the answer to this question as @ClockSlave had suggested. According to the following error line,

```
File "/home/nayantara/PycharmProjects/BSG/libraries/data_iterators/open_text_data_iterator.py", line 2, in <module>
from support import deal_with_accents
ImportError: No module named 'support'
```

the 2<sup>nd</sup> line of import statement in the `open_text_data_iterator.py` file needs to be modified as follows.

```
from libraries.data_iterators.support import deal_with_accents
```

This fixed my issue.